# jquery drag and drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am using jquery for drag-and-drop and it works fine with 2 divs, I can drag an image across 2 divs. One div can be dragged while the other can be dropped upon.

What I want is to have 4 divs, where I have images in each div and I can drag an image from one div to another.

Is this possible in jquery? If yes can you write a little code for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check Jquery Demo from Jquery website or

check this

http://web-design-dubai-uae.blogspot.com/2009/09/jquery-drag-and-drop.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out these [jQuery Examples](http://www.noupe.com/jquery/50-amazing-jquery-examples-part1.html), specifically the [Sortables Demo](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/sort.html)

Comment: dear this is not my question, my question is
i have more than 3 divs and inside div i have pictures
i want to sort pictures among divs using jqury

Comment: view the source of the sortables demo, it will work with images inside of there too

Answer (score 0):

You need to use (and include) JQuery UI to use the $('#something').draggable() and $('#something').droppable() functions.

You can make as much items as you want draggable or droppable and create different functions for each one. Its pretty easy to work with.

This is the best example with the most functionality:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager